# Python-Kruskal Wallis--> Dunn Post Hoc Test

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikits, posthoc

We have the following data (PM1, PM2.5,PM10) and for each we have a before during and after ie: (PM1before,PM1during,PM1after).

We did the kruskal wallis test for PM1 and got:

```
KruskalResult(statistic=72.43619772684008, pvalue=1.865002930642623e-16)
```

We then tried to do the Dunn test as such:

```
x=[[str(PM1before)],[str(PM1during)],[str(PM1after)]]
sp.posthoc_dunn(x)
```

We got the following:
           1       2      3
1   -1.000000   0.4795  0.157299
2   0.479500    -1.0000 0.479500
3   0.157299    0.4795  -1.000000

For some reason, regardless of which PM (PM1,PM2.5, PM10) we measure we get the same table from the dunn test.

- Is this normal?
- Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you, if anything needs clarification please let me know

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear the `sp` prefix in your example refers to the `scikit_posthoc` package. As far I can interpret your example you tried to use `strings` inside the 2-dimensional list, which doesn't make sense...

[posthoc_dunn](https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/scikit_posthocs.posthoc_dunn/#scikit_posthocs.posthoc_dunn)

You have to use numbers inside the 2-dimensional list. `x` in your example needs numbers...